# Can't submit timesheets on Project 2007 and Server 2008R2 new install

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql, sharepoint-2007, microsoft-project

I'm trying to test move a SharePoint 2007 and Project 2007 to Server 2008R2 and using SQL 2008 as the backend.  I'm setting it up just like I have done numerous times for Server '03 and there are no problems with those deployments.

I have fresh copies of MOSS/MOPS with all Service Packs installed, every thing installs fine, I start services on the farm, create SSP and necessary web apps, then create the PWA site.  I define time periods then create a timesheet, enter time, hit save, and I get "While communicating with the Project Server an error occurred.  Check connectivity with your administrator to determine if further action is necessary"

I can do Recalculate and I also can do Save and Submit without any trouble though.  Save and Submit processes through the queue and my timesheet is then auto approved.

If I go and setup an Server 2003 box with the same as above I have no problems.  What could I be missing on 08r2?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to disable Dynamic Compression in IIS.  So for those of you that come across problems on a R2 build check there first.